# left/right join performance

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a different between in left and right join, the below sql statements are same result, but is the both is the same performance?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM writers
  RIGHT JOIN blogs ON blogs.members_id = model_id
WHERE member_id = 123 AND blogs.status = 1;



SELECT count(*)
FROM blogs
  LEFT JOIN writers ON writers.model_id = blogs.members_id
WHERE writers.member_id = 123
      AND blogs.status = 1;
```

Comment: What do your own tests tell you?

Comment: They both have similar performance. The only thing that it differ is that which record you want to get. If Left Join/Right Join vs Inner Join then I can tell Inner Join is a lot quicker since it does not return records that does not match its criteria unlike Right/Left Join they will return null which will give a little load in its performance to retrieve those data.

Comment: Neither statement is actually really performing a left / right join, the where clause predicates are changing the meaning to that of an inner join.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware my test is the same. I want to be sure there is nothing behind engine affect on performance .

Answer (score 4):

No difference at all.  Both are implementing *inner joins*.  Huh?  You think you specified an `outer join`, but your `where` clause is undoing it.

Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM blogs b LEFT JOIN
     writers w
     ON w.model_id = b.members_id AND w.member_id = 123
WHERE b.status = 1;
```

Although you can write this as a `RIGHT JOIN`, I strongly discourage it.  Here are some reasons:

- SQL is read left-to-right.  It is easier to follow "keep all the rows in the first table" than "keep all the rows in the last table which I haven't yet read".
- SQL is parsed left-to-right.  For a single join, this doesn't make a difference.  But with multiple joins, there are subtle differences between A LEFT JOIN B LEFT JOIN C and C RIGHT JOIN B RIGHT JOIN A.